# A question about a primality test for $3^n-2$ and $N-1$ or $N+1$ factorization

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

**Context :**

I'm interested by numbers, prime and composite numbers and their properties, perfect and hyperperfect numbers and primality testing.

Recently, I discovered the Lucas-Lehmer primality test for Mersenne numbers $2^p-1$ where $p$ is a prime number, and more generally the Lucas-Lehmer-Riesel test. I think the Lucas-Lehmer test for Mersenne numbers is interesting because it a fast and deterministic test. And I'm asking if it can work for numbers like $3^n-2$ for example by changing the sequence.

**Problematic :**

During my research about primality testing, I read a lot of times than the Lucas-Lehmer tests works because, it part, $N+1$ can be easily factorized (in this case, small numbers and each time the same).

But I found later some primality tests that seems working even if $N-1$ or $N+1$ isn't easily factorizable for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394160/conjectured-compositeness-tests-for-n-k-cdot-2n-pm-c)

So the easiness of factorization is really a necessary condition for Lucas-Lehmer or Lucas-Lehmer-Riesel primality test ? I don't understand this and why It should be like that. I think I'm missing something but I don't know what. I'm really interested by explainations for this.

So primality testing for numbers of the form $3^n-2$ shouldn't work here.

But we know already some factors of $3^n-3$, so $N-1$, here, the factor are obviously $2$ and $3$, so it's not enough to start a primality test for $3^n-2$, even probabilistic ? the Lucas-Lehmer-Riesel test works even if the $N+1$ factor are different and not the same numbers.

So what is the "threshold" of the easiness of factorization ?

**A probable primality test for $3^n-2$ ?**

I don't know if this probable primality test has counterexample but I tried with all $n < 10000$ and no counterexample was found.

The test looks like the Lucas-Lehmer test but with different starting value and sequence :

The test :

Let $R_n = 3^n-2$ when $n$ is a number $\ge 3$.

Let the sequence $S_i = 16 \cdot S_{i-1}^3 + 96 \cdot S_{i-1}^2 + 192 \cdot S_{i-1} + 126 $ where $S_0 = 126$.

Then $R_n$ is prime if $S_{n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod {R_n}$.

How I found the coefficients of the sequence :

Some intuition here, and I think It can help a lot for proving if the test can works or not for all $n$.

I solved this equation system :

$$\begin{cases} 
a \cdot (2^{3^1-2}-2)^3 + b \cdot (2^{3^1-2}-2)^2 + c \cdot (2^{3^1-2}-2) +d = (2^{3^2-2}-2) \\
a \cdot (2^{3^2-2}-2)^3 + b \cdot (2^{3^2-2}-2)^2 + c \cdot (2^{3^2-2}-2) +d = (2^{3^3-2}-2) \\
a \cdot (2^{3^3-2}-2)^3 + b \cdot (2^{3^3-2}-2)^2 + c \cdot (2^{3^3-2}-2) +d = (2^{3^4-2}-2) \\
a \cdot (2^{3^4-2}-2)^3 + b \cdot (2^{3^4-2}-2)^2 + c \cdot (2^{3^4-2}-2) +d = (2^{3^5-2}-2) \\
\end{cases}$$

This is how I found $a = 16, b = 96, c = 192, d = 126$.

If there are false positive I think these are Carmichael numbers and especially if $3^n-2$ is a Carmichael number but I found none and I don't know if it's possible.

So I have two questions is : Is this test works all the time ? and for $N-1$ and $N+1$ factorization, why this is so important ?

Comment: I do not think that there is an easy prime certificate of $3^n-2$ for every positive integer $n$ for which $3^n-2$ is prime. Usually, for such tests it is required , as you mentioned , that $N-1$ or $N+1$ can be easily factored which is not the case here. Did you check the test you derived ?

Comment: If we apply simply a weak fermat 2-PRP test , it gives the correct result for $2\le n\le 2\ 000$ , but we won't be able to show that it always holds , although this is probably the case.

Comment: OEIS gives the known positive integers $n$ for which $3^n-2$ is prime : $$[2,4,5,6,9,22,37,41,90,102,105,317,520,541,561,648,780,786,957,1353,2224,2521,6184,7989,8890,19217,20746,31722,37056,69581,195430,225922,506233,761457,1180181]$$

Comment: @Peter thanks for your answer, I've tested the test until $n < 10000$ I will check higher later